# How to show that this limit only exist when $\theta$ $=0,$ $\pi/2$, $\pi$, $3\pi/2$ $\pmod {2 \pi}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

**Question**

Consider the function $f(x,y) = (xy)^{1/3}$

Show that $\nabla f(0,0)=(0,0)$ and that the limit:
$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(t\cos(\theta),t\sin(\theta))}{t}$$
fails to exist when $\theta \neq 0,\pi/2, \pi, 2\pi/3$ $\pmod {2\pi}.$

**Attempt**

I get that $\nabla f =(\frac{y^{1/3}}{3x^{2/3}}, \frac{x^{1/3}}{3y^{2/3}})$ and that the limit is
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(t^2\cos(\theta) \sin(\theta))^{1/3} }{t}$$

but I don't know how to continue with it, I assume it has something to do with the $\nabla f(0,0)=(0,0)$ but $\nabla f(0,0)$ wouldn't exist if $\theta$=$0$

Comment: I think you forgot about the cube root for the limit

Comment: Yeah, what you’ve written as “… and that the limit is…” is not the limkt

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Observe that

$$\frac{f(t\cos\theta\,,\,\,t\sin\theta)}t=\frac{\left(\sin2\theta\right)^{1/3}}{2^{1/3}\,t^{1/3}}$$

The only way the above thing has a limit when $\;t\to0\;$ is if the numerator vanishes...

Comment: Think about what happens when $\theta$ is equal to the points that you listed in your original question. This causes sin$2\theta$ to be equal to 0. And so the numerator vanishes here @clamp

Comment: Right, I didn't see the original question well enough, but what do I do with the $t^{1/3}$ in the denominator? if t goes to zero that means the denominator also goes to 0 @FD_bfa

Comment: @clamp If the numerator vanishes then you have the limit when $\;t\to0\;$ of zero, which is zero. If $\;\theta\neq0,\frac\pi2\frac{3\pi}2\mod{2\pi}\;$ then the numerator is a non-zero number and you have the limit of a number divided by $\;t^{1/3}\;$ when $\;t\to0\;$ , which doesn't even exist (as the limit from the left is different from the limit from the right)

Answer (score 0):

We consider the limit as $t\rightarrow 0$ for the function $\frac{\left(\sin2\theta\right)^{1/3}}{2^{1/3}\,t^{1/3}}$. We have two possibilities where the numerator is equal to $0$ or is not equal to $0$ and we will consider these in two cases separately below:

**Case 1**

If ($\sin 2\theta)^{1/3}$ is non-zero then as we take the limit the function diverges to infinity. Since we are dividing by a variable that approaches $0$.

That is because we know for $\alpha \neq 0$, that $\frac{\alpha}t$ converges to $\infty$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.

**Case 2**

However, we can resolve this problem by considering what happens when ($\sin 2\theta)^{1/3}$ = $0$. Now when we take the limit, when we take the limit we converge to $0$. In this case, the limit **does** exist.

Note: we can see this directly as when the numerator is equal to $0$, we see that

$\frac{\left(\sin2\theta\right)^{1/3}}{2^{1/3}\,t^{1/3}}$ = $\frac{0}{2^{1/3}\,t^{1/3}}=0$ and so it is clear that when $t \rightarrow  0$, this doesn't affect the fact that the function will always be equal to $0$, and so the limit is well defined at these points.

We now try to find the values of $\theta$ that make the numerator equal to $0$. We know that:

$$(\sin2\theta)^{\frac{1}3}=0 \iff \sin2\theta=0 \iff \theta=0,\frac{\pi}2,\pi, ...$$

**Conclusion**

The limit exists when $\theta=0,\frac{\pi}2,\pi, ...$ however, when theta is any other value, the limit does not exist as we end up diverging to infinity as t approaches $0$.